# Understanding list of Func delegate (lambda expression)

Tags: c#

I started using lambda expression and I use it often now but only the simple ones :-). Sometime I really get confused understanding lambda expressions in our existing code base. Tried hard to understand the code below but still not able to decipher completely :-(. I think because of the use of Func delegate I am not able to understand. I know that Func delegate is used when the delegate returns some thing. But in this case no clue.

Code snippet:

```
 public class PrintProvider
 {
     private readonly IInstructionSheetViews _instructionSheetViews;
     public PrintProvider(IInstructionSheetViews instructionSheetViews)
     {
         _instructionSheetViews = instructionSheetViews;
     }
     public void AddReport()
     {
  // Some implementation code goes here
         var printViews = _instructionSheetViews.PrintViews;
  // Some implementation code goes here
     }
 }

public class InstructionSheetViews : IInstructionSheetViews
 {
     private readonly IInstructionSheetFactory _factory;
     private IEnumerable<IReport> _instructionSheetView;
     private List<Func<IInstructionSheetFactory, IReport>> _instructionSheetViewList;

    public InstructionSheetViews(IInstructionSheetFactory factory)
     {
         _factory = factory;
     }

    public IEnumerable<IReport> PrintViews
     {
         get
         {
             if (_instructionSheetView == null)
             {
                 Init();
                 _instructionSheetView = _instructionSheetViewList.Select(x => x(_factory));
             }

            return _instructionSheetView;
         }
     }

    private void Init()
     {
          _instructionSheetViewList = new List<Func<IInstructionSheetFactory, IReport>>();
         _instructionSheetViewList.Add(x => x.BuildCommonData());
         _instructionSheetViewList.Add(x => x.BuildSpecificData());
     }
 }
```

In the above code snippet, AddReport method calls "_instructionSheetViews.PrintViews" and this method inturn calls "Init()".

Q1. What is exactly getting added to "_instructionSheetViewList" here -

```
    _instructionSheetViewList.Add(x => x.BuildCommonData());.
```

What I can guess is, it adds a method that returns a "IReport". But "_instructionSheetViewList" contains a list of "Func". So, Ideally isn't it that it should contain a method that takes input as "IInstructionSheetFactory" and return "IReport"?

Q2. How does this statement works. Basically the control flow.

```
_instructionSheetViewList.Select(x => x(_factory));
```

Can someone please explain me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q1: Adds a func delegate to a deferred method invocation.  Q2: invokes the deferred method.  That's it.

Comment: _" isn't it that it should contain a method that takes input as "IInstructionSheetFactory" and return "IReport"?"_ -- yes, and that's exactly what `x => x.BuildCommonData()` is. So, what's your question? _"Can someone please explain me?"_ -- what don't you understand? Did you read the documentation for the `Select()` method? Did you read the documentation regarding delegates and how they are invoked? Your questions are far too vague to know what answer you need here...SO isn't an ideal forum for explaining broad concepts in the first place, but if you want help you need to be _more specific_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 _instructionSheetViewList.Add(x => x.BuildCommonData());
```

is equivalent to -

```
private IReport GetReport(IInstructionSheetFactory x)
    {
        return x.BuildCommonData();
    }
```

And when you do this -

```
_instructionSheetViewList.Select(x => x(_factory));
```

it actually calls a method with Func as a input parameter to that method
which inturn calls the method referenced by Func delegate with _factory as input parameter

```
private IReport DoSomething(Func<IInstructionSheetFactory, IReport> x)
    {
        return x(_factory);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> So, Ideally isn't it that it should contain a method that takes input as "IInstructionSheetFactory" and return "IReport"?

It does. `_instructionSheetViewList.Add(x => x.BuildCommonData());` is basically equivalent to this:

```
 _instructionSheetViewList.Add(anonymousMethod12345);
/*...*/
public static IReport anonymousMethod12345 (IInstructionSheetFactory x)
{
    return x.BuildCommonData();
}
```